# Javascript Array Object And Values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, extjs

Hey all I have a chunk of code that I've been three days trying to pull a tiny bit of data from.

I know there is a LOT of code here but all I need is my (changed) name, in this case, William Adama from the last array object.

I would appreciate any help as I've been three days trying to figure it out and I'm TERRIBLE at Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function applyArguments(){
    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/s.gif';
    Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL = 's.gif';
    Ext.ns('acronym.ngoe.args');
    Ext.apply(acronym.ngoe, {
        soaUrl: './',
        //Global Service Url (terminate with '/' !!)
        scSoaUrl: '/crm/',
        sbpdatapath: '/SupportbyProduct/',
        basepath: '',
        assetsUrl: '/ngoeSitecacheDocs/',
        localeString: 'en_US',
        systemurl: '/',
        jsonUrl: '/ngoeSitecacheDocs/en_US/',
        jsonUrlExtended: '/ngoeSitecacheDocs/en_US/pages/support_zone_web_assets/products/',
        loginsystemurl: 'https://sso.acronym.com/',
        talismaChatUrl: 'https://chatlb.acronym.com/NaRouter/nadispatch.aspx',
        attachmentsUrl: 'https://fileservice.acronym.com/AttachmentsV3/Index.aspx',
        freemarkercontextpath: '/',
        downloadsdatapath: '/downloads/',
        downloadsUrl: 'http://nglznddev01.isus.acronym.com/downloads/',
        emailAddress: 'William.Adama@acronym.com',
        viewandManageSRUrl: '/crm/srManagement/',
        orderACRUUrl: '/crm/orderPart',
        administersiteUrl: '/crm/sites/',
        dnllandingUrl: '/downloads/',
        licenseUrl: '/crm/license/',
        createSRUrl: '/crm/createSR/',
        chatUrl: '/crm/liveChat/',
        forumUrl: '/community/',
        sclandingUrl: '/crm/',
        releaseAndEndOfLifeDatesCustomer: 'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname',
        releaseAndEndOfLifeDatesPartner: 'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname&internalId=0b01406680021db6&_irrt=true',
        releaseAndEndOfLifeDatesEmployee: 'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname&internalId=0b014066800251dd&_irrt=true',
        sbpIssuesPowerlinkCustomerUrl:'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname&internalId=0b014066800a8d8f&_irrt=true',
        sbpIssuesPowerlinkPartnerUrl:'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname&internalId=0b014066800a9053&_irrt=true',
        sbpIssuesPowerlinkEmployeeUrl:'http://protectedlink.acronym.com/someappname&internalId=0b014066800a9053&_irrt=true',
        chatViewAllUrl:'https://community.acronym.com/docs/DOC-XXXXX',
        isNewLiveChat:'true',
        showContentSubscriptions: 'false',
        communityIFIUrl: 'https://sso.acronym.com/sso/ifi/ifiProcessor?initiatingURL=https://community.acronym.com/communitysupport/'

    });

    acronym.ngoe.args = {
        disableOverlays: true,
        preloadOverlays: false,
        enableSessionNotification: true,
        sessionNotificationInMin: 240,
        sessionGracePeriodInMin: 3,
        sessionUpdateNotification: 2,
        sortBy: '0',
        showSubscriptions: 'true',
        eliteAccess : 'true',
        ecpsAccess : 'true',
        ecpsPocAccess : 'true',
        enableSupportIcon : 'true',
        mySupportUrl : '/myproducts/',
        myProductsMenuItemVisible : 'true',
        chatInterval : 30,
        chatNonSelectedIntervalInSecs: 90,
        chatNonSelectedMaxCycles: 4,
        sfdcAuthorPageUrl : 'https://acronym.my.sforce.net.com/knowledge/publishing/knowledgePublishingHome.apexp',
        sfdcAccessLevelCheck : 'true',
        rcmCodeKey : 'ACRONYM_ONSITE_REASON_FOR_RCM'

    };
    Ext.apply(acronym.ngoe.args, {"userData":{"title":"Tech Support Engineer I IRL","uid":"138942","firstName":"William","lastName":"Adama","preferredLocale":"en_US","loginName":"adamaw3","siteDuns":null,"parentDuns":null,"phoneNumber":"353851234567","identityType":"E","customerType":null,"companyName":"","accessLevel":50,"email":"William.Adama@acronym.com","givenname":"William","isCRMUser":true,"customerProgram":null,"subscribenetMemberID":null,"globalDuns":null,"localeLang":"en","localeCountry":"US","flname":"William Adama","sfdcUserType":"Platform User"},"docsPerPage":"50"});
    Ext.apply(acronym.ngoe.args, {"supportBean":{"readOnly":false,"firstName":"William","lastName":"Adama","entityId":null,"partyId":27132777,"siteDuns":null,"userId":452198,"respId":58727,"respAppId":514,"sites":null,"userFlag":"E","crmUser":true,"groupId":null,"resourceId":100499257,"phoneNumber":null,"emailAddress":null,"powerlinkId":"138942","requestType":null,"supportFlag":null,"empFlag":null,"personId":400710,"relPartyId":null,"emailPointId":null,"phonePointId":null,"admin":false,"agent":false,"adminPartyId":null,"relationshipCode":null,"relationshipType":null,"requestUser":null,"entitledDuns":null,"roleName":null,"identifyType":null,"phoneCountryCode":"null","phoneAreaCode":"null","dialOutAccess":true,"userSupportedCountry":"IE"}});
    Ext.apply(acronym.ngoe.args, {"neoBeanData":{"notes":null,"chatType":null,"serialNo":null,"defectivepartNo":null,"defectivepartserialNo":null,"sline":null}});

    acronym.ngoe.arguments = acronym.ngoe.args;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext doesn't really play much of a factor here, just using some shortcuts to assign objects properties.

Anyway, you'd access it with:

```
console.log(acronym.ngoe.args.userData.firstName);
console.log(acronym.ngoe.args.userData.lastName);
```